# Can you use older blender addons in newer versions

Tags: add-on

For example if you have an addon that works with 2.9 can you use it with 3.0??

Comment: depends on the add-on

Answer (score 4):

Older addons will work with newer releases if they don't use functionality that was changed between the two releases.  2.9 Addons that use 2.9 style Geometry Nodes probably won't work in 3.0 because there were widespread changes in Geometry Nodes.  Addons that consist of collections of Cycles materials probably will; because Cycles X maintained material compatibility with Cycles.  Even if functionality didn't change, sometimes changes in the Python interface will break an old add-on.

You can research what broke between releases by looking at Release notes.  Here are the [3.0 Python Release Notes](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/3.0/Python_API) for example.  You can see a list of Breaking Changes part way down.  If an add-on relied on any of that, it won't work.

In the end, the only way to find out for certain is to try, although the more certain way is to wait for the add-on developer to either post a version that will work or a notice saying that the old version does work.